# SSRS Drill through Parent report to Child report with 2 parameters

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, reportingservices-2005, drillthrough

I want to drill through from Parent Report to Child Report, Where 2 columns from Parent acts as Parameter to child.

[image: EXAMPLE DESIGN]
I made 2 parameters Hidden, because value will be retrieved by Parent report.
But I m getting "The 'ColB' parameter is missing a value".
I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've not given any details about the report parameters on the child report and how you have assigned them

Typically you would set an action on a textbox that is in your parent report. In the action properties, you would choose Go To Report and then choose the subreport name. Then you would add parameters and set the parameter name to `ColA` (case sensitive - this the parameter name in your child report) to your ColA field (`[ColA]`) from your parent report dataset (you should be able to choose this from the parameter value dropdown), then repeat for parameter @ColB.

That's all there is too it. If this does not help, show your settings in the TerxtBox properties Action tab.

Comment: Hi Alan, I have done exactly same , The parameter @ColA is getting passed. But when drilling through to child report , I m getting error 'ColB' Parameter is missing a value.

Comment: Do yo have a list of available values in the subreport for `ColB`? If so try removing that list as it might be the value you are passing is not in the list and therefore invalid. If not, edit your question and some screenshots of you child report parameter properties and the textbox action tab where the parameters are being set. Also, try hardcoding the ColB parameter to a known good value, that might help narrow the problem down.

Comment: Hi Alan, Thanks for all suggestions. I was able to acheive things. It was working fine when I deploy reports , but not when running from Visual Studio.  I will mark your solution as answer, so that it helps future readers.